# Gstreamer with opencv how to setup parameters for icecast2

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, icecast

I am building program where have to stream video to server because no display(hdmi) is available. I was testing streaming with `videotestsrc` and everything works fine, but using real data is problem. I don't know how to setup gstreamer for my data. How I can get format of my video?

I would like to stream black and white cv::Mat and 3chanell cv::Mat.

I was following this tutorial:
https://www.google.sk/amp/s/schneide.wordpress.com/2015/03/03/streaming-images-from-your-application-to-the-web-with-gstreamer-and-icecast-part-1/amp/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCv's videowriter directly and pass the pipe to videwriter. You need to replace `videotestsrc` with `appsrc` :

```
float fps = 25.0f; // or the fps you desire
int fourcc = 0;
bool is_color = true; // depending on your image
cv::VideoWriter writer;
writer.open("appsrc ! vp8enc ! webmmux ! shout2send ip=127.0.0.1 port=8000 password=hackme mount=/test.webm", fourcc,fps, frame.size());

...

writer.write(frame);

writer.release();
```